# Mobiscroll clear button

Tags: mobiscroll

I would like to implement a clear button showed on popup in mobiscroll date picker
There is an option to use `button3`, however I'm not able to clear the input and hide the scroller.

```
jQuery(this).mobiscroll({
        preset: 'date',
        theme:'ios',
        button3Text:'clear',
        button3: function(input, inst){
            jQuery(this).val();
            inst.close();
        }})
```

I was trying use the input and `inst` parameter from function.
Unfortunately I'm not able to make it work.

Could you plese help?

Thanks Lucas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solve the problem.
I couldn't get the instance but when I save the object first

```
 var thisPicker = jQuery(this);
```

and on button3 get the instance,

```
var inst = thisPicker.mobiscroll('getInst');
```

everything works fine.

Whole code...

```
// Date mobiscroll picker init
jQuery(".datepicker").each(function (index, element) {

    var thisPicker = jQuery(this);
    jQuery(this).mobiscroll({
        preset: 'date',
        theme:'ios',
        display : 'bottom',
        button3Text:'X',
        button3: function(){
            var inst = thisPicker.mobiscroll('getInst');
            thisPicker.val('');
            inst.cancel();

        },

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that there is an option to enable "clear" button from within mobiscroll config:

http://docs.mobiscroll.com/2-15-1/mobiscroll-core#!opt-buttons

> Buttons to display. **Predefined buttons are: 'set', 'clear', 'cancel'.** Custom buttons can also be specified: